# match each cell with a range and return value

Tags: vba, excel

Completely new to VBA coding but working on a project. Need help!

I have a set of dates in Column J. I have to manually enter dates in cells B3, C3, D3 .... so on till K3. If the dates in the cells B3 to K3 (only if values are present in these cells) match the date in column J then i have to autofill Column H with value "Create". (Not necessary that all cells from B3 to K3 will be filled). I tried doing this coding, but throwing error. Can someone help me in fixing my Code? Thanks.

```
Sub NDate_Input()
'
'Autofill for Create Date & Update Date
'

'
    Worksheets("ORD_CS").Activate
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ORD_CS")
    LR = sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    With sht
        For i = 8 To LR
            If Range("B3:K3").Value = Range("J" & i).Value Then
                Range("H" & i).Value = "Create"
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Run-time error 13? You can't compare that Range B3:K3 to a single cell

Comment: Exactly. Run-time error 13. How do i compare each cell from B3 to K3 with the column J?

Comment: Iterate the cells, compare the cells. Say what you do, do what you say! ;-)

Comment: Note that if any of the cells involved contains an error (e.g. `#VALUE!`), you'll *still* run into error 13.

Answer (score 1):

Place this code inside the sheet module where the data is and it will fire each time you change a date in `B3:K3`.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B3:K3")) Is Nothing Then

        If Target.Value <> vbNullString Then

            Dim findMe as Range
            Set findMe = Range("J1:J100000").Find(Target.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)

            If Not findMe Is Nothing Then

                Range("H" & findMe.Row).Value = "Create"

            End If

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub NDate_Input()
    Dim i As Long, nVals As Long
    Dim str As String

    With Worksheets("ORD_CS")
        With .Range("B3:K3")
            str = WorksheetFunction.Trim(Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Value)), " "))
            nVals = WorksheetFunction.Count(.Cells)
        End With
        For i = 8 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count
            If WorksheetFunction.Trim(WorksheetFunction.Rept(.Range("J" & i).Value & " ", nVals)) = str Then .Range("H" & i).Value = "Create"
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @ DisplayName - The code isn't throwing any error but am not getting the result.